# How find this value $m^2-mn-n^2$

Tags: fractions, fibonacci-numbers

let

> $$1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\cdots\dfrac{1}{1}}}}}=\dfrac{m}{n}$$

where $m,n$ are positive integer numbers,and such $gcd(m,n)=1$.,and article $1998$ the fractional line on the left.

**Find the value:**

**$m^2-mn-n^2$**

and This problem is from this:http://www.mathchina.com/cgi-bin/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=18459&show=0

and my try:

if **Left hand** have infinite the fractional line, we have

> $$1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\cdots}}}}=x$$
>   $$\Longrightarrow x=1+\dfrac{1}{x}\Longrightarrow x=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

but left only have $1998$ the fractional line.so How find it ? Thank you

Comment: You know that if we stop at any time the fraction we get is the ratio of consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Corrected title.

Comment: @AndréNicolas,How can you post this problem with the Fiboncacci numbers? Thank you

Comment: read this and the earlier bits for methods http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions

Comment: Meanwhile, is it $m^2 + mn - n^2$ or is it $m^2 - m n - n^2$ or something other? It matters. If this is going to be an easy problem it has got to be $m^2 - m n - n^2$ but you typed two other (and different) versions. The trouble is $m/n$ is about the golden ratio so $m$ is the larger one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_0=1$ and $x_{k+1}=1+\frac1{x_k}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Suppose that $x_k=\frac{m_k}{n_k}$, where $m_k,n_k\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then

$$\frac{m_{k+1}}{n_{k+1}}=x_{k+1}=1+\frac1{x_k}=1+\frac{n_k}{m_k}=\frac{m_k+n_k}{m_k}\;.$$

Thus, we can get correct fractions by setting

$$\begin{align*}
&m_0=n_0=1\;,\tag{1}\\
&m_{k+1}=m_k+n_k\;,\text{ and}\tag{2}\\
&n_{k+1}=m_k\;.\tag{3}
\end{align*}$$

$(3)$ implies that $n_k=m_{k-1}$ for $k\ge 1$, so $(2)$ can be rewritten $$m_{k+1}=m_k+m_{k-1}\;,\tag{4}$$ with $m_0=1$ and $m_1=m_0+n_0=2$. Thus, $m_0=F_2$ and $m_1=F_3$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Now you can use known closed forms for the Fibonacci numbers to compute $m_{1998}=F_{2000}$ and $n_{1998}=m_{1997}=F_{1999}$.

**Added:** Then use the fact that

$$\begin{align*}
F_{k+1}^2-F_kF_{k+1}-F_k^2&=(F_{k+1}-F_k)(F_{k+1}+F_k)-F_kF_{k+1}\\
&=F_{k-1}F_{k+2}-F_kF_{k+1}\\
&=F_{k-1}F_k+F_{k-1}F_{k+1}-F_kF_{k+1}\\
&=F_{k-1}F_{k+1}-F_k(F_{k+1}-F_{k-1})\\
&=F_{k-1}F_{k+1}-F_k^2\\
&=(-1)^k
\end{align*}$$

by [Cassini’s identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Other_identities). (I’m assuming that the quadratic is supposed to be $n^2-mn-m^2$.)

Comment: A contest question is meant to be done with pencil & paper. I doubt that, say, Binet's formula is very useful here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I think the OP messed up the quadratic form; in any case he gave two different versions. It has got to be $m^2 - m n - n^2$ to work out easily. The Lagrange reduced version would be $-m^2 + mn + n^2.$ The trouble is that $m$ is the larger of the two numbers...

Comment: @WillJagy: Agree 100%. To tell you the truth, I didn't bother checking the signs of the quadratic form until now, as there is only one combination that makes the question tractable :-)

Comment: Brian, I put the quadratic form in the question to what it must be to have anything work out, well, prettily. It would be nice if we heard from the OP in the next twelve hours, say, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Nice,Thank you very much,+1

Comment: @Jyrki: I missed the fact that it was a contest question at first, but I was in fact looking for a nice finish. I wasn’t following the comments here, so I had to discover the probable typo the hard way.

Comment: @math110: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Brian, of course! Sorry about sounding critical at first. This OP has posted several contest-math problems in the past, which made it easier for me. Also, I solved a variant of this problem at IMO1981, so with that bit of extra it was immediately clear what is required.

Comment: @Jyrki: No problem!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: (Assuming that the correct version of the question asks for $m^2-mn-n^2$.) Try to write
$$
(m+n)^2-(m+n)m-m^2
$$
in terms of $m^2-mn-n^2$, and observe that
$$
1+\frac1{\frac m n}=\frac{m+n}m.
$$